# kdesu freezes after entering password

Tags: kde, su

I have Debian 10 Buster with KDE.

I can't launch any program with `kdesu`. After entering a root password in `kdesu` window, it freezes and hangs up.

How to find why? Maybe there's other ways to start applications as root without using `kdesu`?

Console output:

```
root@debian:~# partitionmanager
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.

root@debian:~# grub-customizer
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(grub-customizer:5153): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:54:55.071: cannot open display:
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes - mx Linux with XFCe ))

Answer (score 0):

`kdesu` might freeze if an incorrect password is typed in.

You've mentioned you're typing your root password into the `kdesu`. However, most likely it expects not the root password, but a password of your current user instead. That's why you're tyoing an incorrect password fot the situation and it freezes.

Comment: I tried to enter current user password. The answer was 'Current user is not in sudoers list'.
One of the 'solutions' was to add user to sudoers list, but it is a bad way.

Comment: @Eldar `kdesu` expects a password for the current user. You've entered a password for another user. Obviously, it's a wrong password in this situation. That's the answer to your question - why `kdesu` freezes.